# Vanilla 5.4.249: Boot signed kernel

Tags: grub2, kernel

I rebuilt vanilla 5.4.249 (x86_64) downloaded from kernel.org
It boots Ok.
Then I tried to sign bzImage using the same procedure I found for ubuntu:
[sign linux kernel for secure boot](https://gloveboxes.github.io/Ubuntu-for-Azure-Developers/docs/signing-kernel-for-secure-boot.html)

But I got:
error: bad shim signature

I'm booting the signed kernel with signed grub 2.06 I installed with knoppix 9.1.
Signed grub is booting Ok.

Is it possible that the signing procedure for Ubuntu is different from the procedure for Vanilla ?
Should I sign the kernel with the same keys used to sign grub ?

Thank you,
Zvika